# Symfony2 FOS REST URL routing

Tags: rest, symfony, fosuserbundle

I provide a REST interface in Symfony2 with FOS

```
    public function approveAction(EducaEvent $id) { ... }
```

but I'm not able to guess the routing interface: I know that it is a patch, but

```
patch_educaevent_approve
patch_educaevents_approve
patch_approve_educaevents
patch_approve_educaevent
```

don't work.
Is there a way to read REST routing string?
What is the routing string in this case?

Comment: Did you find the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug your routes, use:

```
./app/console router:debug
```